# Osmotic Pressure: Comparing Solutes and Ideal Gases

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas, physical-chemistry, osmosis

The equation describing osmotic pressure is

$\Pi=\frac{n}{V} RT $

which is just like the ideal gas equation law

$PV=nRT$

So how much of an analogy is there between ideal gases and solutes?  Is there a extended version of the equation for osmotic pressure that matches the [van der Waals equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation)?

If solutes can be in a state like a gas, can they also be in a state like a liquid?  Is this distinct from a precipitate which would be the analog of a solid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The van t'Hoff equation for the osmotic pressure can be expanded by a [virial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_expansion) similarly to the extension of ideal gas equation. In the gas case, the coefficients of the virial expansion are related to the van der Waals constants a and b. Thus you can probably also obtain a similar equation of state for the osmotic pressure $\Pi$ of a solute. However, their interpretation will probably be different.

Comment: The van der Waal equation has a liquid phase, so it makes me wonder that while ordinarily precipitates are solid, if there aren't substances that 'precipitate' out of an aqueous solution to a liquid form.

Comment: @David Elm - There are many examples of solutes "precipitating"  as liquids that are, e.g., connected to a so-called *miscibility gap*. A simple example for phenol in water is given here http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23519/can-there-be-more-solvent-in-a-solute/23522

Comment: -Thanks.  That's one of the things I looked for, but just didn't hit on the right key words to find.